# How to create admin and front view in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to develope an application with codeigniter

I want sperate my admin and front view, contrller and models

searched on many blogs but couldn'y get it

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to CI, please follow these tutorial:
[CI Official Tutorial](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html) or [CI Video Tutorial](http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/)

If you are expert, please elaborate exactly what problem you are facing.